# Trying to make an option in a console program that outputs a user-defined amount of perfect squares

Tags: c#, loops

```
else if (userAnswer.Equals("2"))
            {
                blankspace();
                Console.WriteLine("How many squares would you like to see? ");
                double num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                while (0 >= num)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(num * num);                      
                }
            }
```

My problem is that I don't know where to go from here. I had previously been able to output just one square, but I need to know how to output a list instead of just a single number.

Comment: you seem aware that you need a loop, though your looping condition is wrong.  Are you wanting to subtract 1 from `num` and display that square till you hit zero?  You need to be more specific on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I would suggest that you use the free tools that are at your disposal, `Google` here is some basic tutorial on While Loops http://www.dotnetperls.com/while [C# Basics Tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/SmartConsoleSetup.aspx)

Comment: Your loop is completely wrong. You have to use counter inside loop. `0 >= num` is always wrong if `num > 0`

Comment: And if `num < 0`, it would loop forever because `num` is not reassigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what your code currently says:

`If the user input is 2:
Add a blank space -- Console.WriteLine() ??
Ask how many squares they want
Get their input
Get the square of their input while their input is less than 0`

As you can see, things go reasonably well until you hit the loop. What I think you're really trying to do is this:

`Get their input
Generate that number of perfect squares`

To accomplish this, your loop should look something more like this:

`for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i * i);
}`

This says the following:

`Start at 1
square the current number (i)
add 1 to the number (i)
repeat until you reach the user's number (num)`

So if the input is `3`, you'll get `1, 2, and 3` squared. If you want to square specific numbers the logic needs to change a bit, but this should at least accomplish your basic goal.

EDIT: If you want to keep the `while` loop, all you really need to do is add `num--` (subtract 1 from num) and switch the comparison to `0 <= num` (assuming you want positive numbers) to stop the infinite loop. This will generate the squares in descending order (3, 2, 1) but accomplish the same result.

You're hitting an infinite loop because `num` never changes so if it doesn't start at 0, it can never be 0.